# Why does it take longer for my program to read files on windows than on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ubuntu

I am basically reading 100000 strings from a `.txt` file and making an AVL tree using the information. The .txt file is 30+ mb.

Using the same program if I compile and run using GCC on UBUNTU it takes around 2 seconds.
On windows using Visual Studio 2013 the it takes around 50 seconds to read from file and build a tree.

EDIT: lets say that my program only has a couple of lines of code that read from a text file and does nothing else. Time is still very similar.

Comment: Are optimizations enables? (I.e. are you compiling /O2?) Are you using the optimized libraries or the debug libraries? Visual Studio includes a profiler; when you profile your app, what is it spending most of its time doing?  Without the code, it's not possible for us to answer the question.

Comment: Most of the time is spent on reading from the file.

Comment: Publish the source code here and provide a link to the text file! The source code in C++ should be only a couple of lines.

Comment: My guess it's an issue with converting \r\n sequences into \n sequences. Open the file in "binary" mode (for fopen, the parameter would be "rb"), and modify your code to be able to ignore any '\r' (carriage return) characters. Since this is a PC, you could allocate 64 mb of memory and read the entire file with a single call.

Comment: NTFS has lower read performance than ext4. But it should not make the huge difference as your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running the program outside of Visual Studio and build it as a Release.  I'm willing to bet a few reputation points that the performance will be better if not on par with Ubuntu.

Comment: If you could bet reputation points, I would take you up on that.

Comment: Brilliant. I built it as release and it took 2.9 seconds.
On par with UBUNTU.